# getting this Type

Tags: c#

```
class TestClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        //which is faster?
        object o1 = MethodRequiringType(typeof(TestClass));
        object o2 = MethodRequiringType(this.GetType());
        //which is better?
        //does it matter?
    }

    public object MethodRequiringType(Type t)
    {
        return new { }; 
    }
}
```

Comment: and now that I'm searching... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983030/type-checking-typeof-gettype-or-is

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139607/what-is-the-difference-between-mycustomer-gettype-and-typeofcustomer-in-c

Comment: Your two statements are not always equivalent. So the answer to the questions for which one is "better" or whether it "matters" is: it depends.

Comment: @Esteban - You're absolutely right.  I suppose the better question is "when should you use which?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google search revealed this:

> GetType is a call that is made at
>   runtime on an instance of an object.
>   typeof() is resolved to a call at
>   runtime, but loads the type from the
>   token for the type. They probably
>   resolve to the same call, it's just
>   that GetType requires an instance. If
>   I didn't need the instance, I would
>   use typeof.

and also:

> Also be aware that GetType is virtual,
>   and gives you the type of the object,
>   not the declared type of the
>   reference. That is:
>
> Object o = new String();
>
> typeof(o) Object type
>
> o.GetType() String type

Comment: In your second example, didn't you mean `o.GetType()` instead of `typeof(o)`  ?

Answer (score 3):

Worry about correctness before performance.  If there are any classes derived from `TestClass`, you won't get the same result.

Comment: What if it was a sealed class?

Comment: Then you'd get the same `Type`, and `typeof` will get it faster.

Answer (score 2):

I've actually measured this difference for a lecture I once gave (on reflection and optimization).

Bottom line: if you plan on calling that line several billion times, you'll save a second using the `typeOf()` instead of the `GetType()`

Comment: I read somewhere (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163759.aspx) with regard to Reflection that the call to GetType was specifically optimized in the JIT compiler, since it is such a commonly used method, as opposed to other Reflection operations such as finding the MemberInfo for a specific member of a type.

Comment: `GetType` is optimized.  That still doesn't make it as fast as `typeof`.

Comment: @Ben, I definitely agree. I didn't mean to sound like I was suggesting to use GetType over typeof in general, so thanks for catching me on that. The article actually mentions that the typeof operation is optimized as well.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the difference is not at all important. There are lots of performance bottlenecks with more impact, than saving a few nanoseconds on a GetType/typeof