# Why can't I do Class.GetMethod() but I can do this.GetType().GetMethod()?

Tags: c#

Why can't I do `Class.GetMethod(string)` but I can do `this.GetType().GetMethod(string)`?

I want to do the former because it seems like it would be a lot quicker since I already know what class I want to search in...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`GetMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx) is a method declared on the [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) class... not on the class you're looking at. (In particular, that class could *also* have a `GetMethod` method, which would confuse things significantly...)

You can use

```
typeof(Class).GetMethod(...)
```

though, rather than getting the type of a specific instance - is that all you were looking for?

EDIT: Note that `GetType(string)` is only declared on `Type` and `Assembly` (and perhaps some other types). The normal `Object.GetType()` method *doesn't* have a string parameter.

Comment: I was guessing that if I could give it something more specific (not a string) it would be faster...so yes, I guess that does help!

Comment: @ovatsug25: What do you mean by "give it something more specific"? Your requirements are very unclear here... the `Class.GetMethod(string)` that you say you want *is* still using a string... I thought you only wanted to get rid of using the call to `this.GetType(string)` - which wouldn't even compile, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

Because the former is how you would call a static method on the class.

If you want to get the type of a class, just use [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx):

```
typeof(Class).GetMethod(someString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do either:

```
typeof (MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");
```

or

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod");
```

Just to add - `myClass.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod")` - Is resolved at runtime, where `typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod")` at compile time.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139607/what-is-the-difference-between-mycustomer-gettype-and-typeofcustomer-in-c) is a bit more on it.

Comment: I don't think your second example is equivalent to the first.  The first example calls the `GetMethod` method of the `Type` class.  The second example attempt to call the `GetMethod` on the `MyClass` type.  If `MyClass` doesn't define a method called `GetMethod`, it will generate a compile error.  Perhaps you meant your second example to be `myClass.GetType().GetMethod("MyMethod")`?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Nope, both will return null if the method is not found. Also did you see my edit (I acknowledge that there is a difference), is this what you mean ?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway yeah I had a typo that I did out of being in a hurry, fixed that.