# Why is this not constant?

Tags: c#

Basically as stated in the title, if I do this:

```
private const string TYPEOF_STRING = typeof(String).FullName;
```

Why does it give me the error of:

> The expression being assigned to
>   'Cognitronics.Generic.CloudClient.TYPEOF_STRING' must be constant

EDIT:

It seems we have conflicting answers here and in the thread Habib linked too. Here everyone has said that it is not a compile time constant, whereas in the other thread everyone says it is. This has just made me even more confused so I would like to re-ask which is it?

Comment: Hmm... isn't that quite self-explanatory?

Comment: @Robert, clearly not, otherwise why would the OP have asked his question? Restriction the "const" keyword to compile-time only constants is a language-specific feature.

Comment: @Robert, actually it is not, [`typeof` is resolved at compile time](http://stackoverflow.com/a/139611/961113)

Comment: @Habib if it is resolved at compile why doesn't it work then? Or am I being daft?

Comment: @habib typeof(T) is not compile time constant. It depends. `Type foo<T>(){ return typeof(T); }`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value of

```
typeof(String).FullName
```

is not a compile time constant, code has to execute to know this value.

Comment: I did not know that, I thought it would already know. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to get it as a constant? Or is there just not much point in trying?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Modify the CLR. Good luck.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder `Console.WriteLine(typeof(String).FullName)`.  Copy/Paste.  Or use `readonly` instead of `const`.  What's the purpose of having the type name as a constant?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I would have to ask why you want it as a constant?

Comment: @D Stanley I forgot about readonly, basically had a brain fart! Thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 1):

**Const** means it is constant at compile time and your code needs to run

Use **readonly** if you want it at run time.

As stated in [official site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) :-

> although a **const** field is a **compile-time constant**, the **readonly** field
>   can be used for **run-time constants**, as in this line: public static
>   readonly uint l1 = (uint)DateTime.Now.Ticks;

And you have just learned one frequently asked interview question ;)

Answer (score 0):

`typeof(string)` returns an object of type `System.Type` and you are accessing a property of that object. Objects don't exist at compile time, so the value of their properties can't be determined to be a constant at compile time. `Fullname` being an abstract property also mean that there's no way to ensure that Fullname is a constant. So even knowing that the first expression will always yield the same result is not enough to determine that the value of Fullname is a constant

The below is the IL produced for `typeof(int)`

```
ldtoken int32
call class [mscorlib]System.Type
     [mscorlib]System.Type::GetTypeFromHandle(valuetype
     [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
```

which includes a call to a method and therefore is clearly not constant.

Answer (score 0):

To use the `const` keyword, the compiler must be able to compute the value assigned at compile time. If it's computed at run time, then the `readonly` keyword should be used.

Both are constants, in so far as the value cannot be changed.

So to declare your constant, use:

```
private readonly string typeOfString = typeof(String).FullName;
```