# Get derived type class

Tags: c#

So, I have the following structure:

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
    public Type TargetType { get; protected set; }
}

public class A : MyBase
{
    public A()
    {
        TargetType = GetType();//Wrong, I need B class type not C
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() { }
}

public class C : B
{
    public C() { }
}
```

Of course, I can receive my type in this way:

```
public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        TargetType = typeof(B);
    }
}
```

Actually, I have to write some code to make the example clearer:

*Class1.cs*

```
public static Dictionary<Type, Type> MyTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
{
    { typeof(B),typeof(BView) }
}

public Class1()
{
    C itemC = new C();
    Class2.Initialize(itemC);
}
```

*Class2.cs*

```
public static Initialize(MyBase myBase)
{
    Type t;
    Class1.MyTypes.TryGetValue(myBase.TargetType, out t);
    //I need get BView but I get null because *myBase.TargetType* is C class type
}
```

Level structure:

- Level 0:(MyBase) - 1 object
- Level 1:(A) - 2 objects
- Level 2:(B) - 100 objects and more
- Level 3:(C) - 80 objects and more

I gave this case in brackets

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: Can you please explain better what you want to achieve?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Your example isn't clear at all.

Comment: I inherited after A about 100 different objects. So I need find derived type in A class (In this case B class)

Comment: System.Type has a 'BaseType'-Property, have you tried that ? You can call GetType().BaseType in a C-Instance and this should return B-Type

Comment: I thought about it but I inherited after B about 80 different objects, so this way is bad too

Comment: Btw, I inherited after abstract class only 2 different objects.

Comment: Why not simply add another entry to the dictionary? I.e. `{ typeof(C),typeof(BView) }`. Or, alternatively, change the dictionary handling so that it checks `if(myObj is B)` instead of `if(typeof(myObj) == typeof(B)`? (this is pseudocode to explain the difference)

Comment: Because it will be a one-to-many relationship and I need one to one. The second part of the sentence: I can not check, because I have over 100 objects (B, B1, B2, B3 ...) and all have to have link

Answer (score 4):

On any instance of an object you can call .GetType() to get the type of that object.

You don't need to set the type on construction

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand completely your question, but these are some possibilities to get informations about a type:

```
var a = new A();
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().Name); // Output: A
Console.WriteLine(a.GetType().BaseType?.Name); // Output: MyBase

var b = new B();
Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().Name); // Output: B
Console.WriteLine(b.GetType().BaseType?.Name); // Output: A

// A simple loop to get to visit the derivance chain
var currentType = b.GetType();
while (currentType != typeof(object))
{
    Console.WriteLine(currentType.Name);
    currentType = currentType.BaseType;
}
// Output: B A MyBase
```

Also, I suggest to read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139607/what-is-the-difference-between-mycustomer-gettype-and-typeofcustomer-in-c?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) about the difference between `GetType` and `typeof`

Hope this helps.

Comment: To extend your answer to what I think is the core of OP's question, notice that `B b = new B()` and `A b = new B()` will yield the same output as is listed for `var b = new B()` in this answer.